# YouTube API: Get the quality of a video via the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

**Is there any way to tell when a video has been fully encoded at its highest definition via the API?**

As far as I can tell, the YouTube API provides the ['state' of a video](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astate) (processing, restricted, deleted, rejected and failed). However, I can't tell if the API also provides the encoding qualities of the video (240p, 360p, 720i, etc...).

Does anyone know how to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html):

> `player.getPlaybackQuality():String`
>
> This function retrieves the actual video quality of the current video. It returns `undefined` if there is no current video. Possible return values are `highres`, `hd1080`, `hd720`, `large`, `medium` and `small`.